# Rust conditional compilation (#[cfg(...)]) with names instead of hard-coded strings?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation, rust-macros

I'd like to use Rust's conditional compilation, e.g.:

```
#[cfg(platform="value")]
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to define a constant `VALUE = "value"`, such that this can be written as

```
#[cfg(platform=VALUE)]
```

As I understand it, I'd need these defined during my build script exec (before compiling the module), but still accessible within `cfg` macros within these files.

Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, any thoughts on an approach that's cleaner than hard-coding the same string repeatedly (and risking typos)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but a typo isn't as bad as it would be in some runtime code as it usually will produce a compile time error just like a typo in the 'hard coded' `VALUE` would.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

However, the Rust developers are aware that `cfg`s are error-prone, and have developed [an accepted (and implemented) RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82450) to help prevent that. With this RFC, the compiler warns about unknown `cfg` values (or names).

[Cargo also has unstable support for this feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#check-cfg). To use it, you need to enable the `-Zcheck-cfg` option in the command line invocation of Cargo. It accepts four values:

- `features` for checking of features `cfg`s.
- `names` for checking of well-known `cfg` names.
- `values` for checking of well-known `cfg` values.
- `output` for checking of custom `cfg`s from build scripts.

To use all checks, pass `-Zcheck-cfg=features,names,values,output` in the command line.

If you have a build scripts outputting custom `cfg`s, you need to enable `-Zcheck-cfg=output` as well as adjust your build scripts to output `cargo:rustc-check-cfg` instructions. They work like the following:

```rust
println!("cargo:rustc-check-cfg=names(platform)");
println!(r#"cargo:rustc-check-cfg=values(platform, "value", "value2")"#);
```